# Google search show my website only if i search for the link itself

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

I uploaded my website, then I add it to Google search to be shown in the results, after a while , I searched for my website by using it's name/unique keywords, but nothing was shown even I searched for the name of my website without(`.com`).
I can only see my website when searching for the website itself(like `example.com`).
Also search results only shows the main page.

Information about the website:

-The website main page redirects to a long URL, for example: openning `example.com` redirects to `example.com/site/catagory/mainCatagory`.

-all links to my website must start with:`example.come/index.php?`.

-I added the meta tags for keywords/discription.

-The website has unique contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can take a very long time for Google to show your site in its search results and can take even longer for better ranking -- unless your content goes viral, which I am assuming it has not. No worries! If you have not done so yet I would add [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) and have Google create an `XML` [sitemap of your site](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184). Google *will* crawl and index your entire site (if you have the tracking code on each page) this way. Remember, you must have the [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) code on every page! I would try using the asynchronous (`Async`) method of embedding your [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) code. Patience is a virtue!

Comment: The only missing thing is creating XML sitemap.

Comment: Yes. Just add an XML sitemap with Google. :)